# No diparity image for stereo vision using prosilica cameras

Tags: ros, stereo, image-view, rqt-image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have started working with two prosilica cameras for stereo vision. At first I downloaded the driver package for prosilica camera driver. I developed two launch files for two cameras in syncin1 and in fixed rate mode. Now after launching the files both the cameras are working. I have checked using rqt as well

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=stereo/left/image_raw
```

but the topic /stereo/disparity is not showing anything. If I try to view the disparity image using

```
rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=stereo/disparity
```

it pops a window but there is nothing. Even in rqt if i go for visualization in the topic list the /stereo/disparity topic is not in the list. I am really stuck in here. Any help will appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197194/no-diparity-image-for-stereo-vision-using-prosilica-cameras/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi saptarshi,

first, you have to run stereo_image_proc and then calibrate the cameras with a chekerboard, as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration). Once the calibration has been saved (or commited), then the disparity image should be available from the topic in stereo_image_proc.

I have a similar setup (two color GigE AVT Manta sync'd), and decided to implement a new driver using the new AVT API VIMBA. The ros node is available [here](http://wiki.ros.org/avt_vimba_camera). I'd be very grateful if you could give it a try.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-11-12**:
hey I have done the calibration and commit it. but still if i view the disparity image using "rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/stereo/disparity" the pop-up window is empty. I have modified the disparity parameter as well but still it is not working.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-11-14**:
Can you show us your launchfile?

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-11-14**:
Saptarshi, check that you are also receiving images from your right camera and that those and synchronized.

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-11-14**:
thanks a lot... I have checked. we have to add _approximate_sync:=True and _queue_size:=10 arguments with the stereo_view node..